# where is the R.java in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

the several R.java is not "that one",I even can't find specific id or layout in those files.

where is that R.java which have layout/menu/id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here

```
Project/app/build/generated/source/r/debug/com.android.'projectname'/R.java
```

Just Don't mess with those files. You don't actually need them. That is for internal referencing.